# How to get the version number of an Excel workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I have an Excel book that's versioned in a Sharepoint document library, so that I can go to the File tab and see versions like:

```
19.0: 11/10/2014 1:15 PM by xyz\tkl2
17.0: 10/12/2014 3:54 PM by xyz\tkl2
14.0: 10/11/2014 2:23 PM by xyz\92jf
```

I want to retrieve the most recent version number, in this case **19.0**.  I've tried using the following code:

```
Sub getVersions()

Dim DocVersions As DocumentLibraryVersions
Dim DVersion As DocumentLibraryVersion

Set DocVersions = ThisWorkbook.DocumentLibraryVersions

For Each DVersion In DocVersions
    Debug.Print DVersion.Index
    Debug.Print DVersion.Comments
    Debug.Print DVersion.Creator
    Debug.Print DVersion.Modified
    Debug.Print DVersion.ModifiedBy
    Debug.Print DVersion.Application
Next

End Sub
```

This is every property that seems possible to get regarding a particular document version.  But none of these properties retrieve the actual version number; e.g., `.Index` would only retrieve **1**, **2**, and **3** for these versions.  Is there a way to get to the actual version number?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information by opening the historical version of the file, and its filename will be *`filename`.xlsx, version`xx.yy`:`modified date`*, so that `xx.yy` will be the version number in the `major.minor` format.

I've put the code I used below. It puts the version name in column H of the sheet that it opens. It's got a little error checking in, but not enough to use straight off. Most importantly, it assumes that the spreadsheet it's pasted in is the only spreadsheet open. You'll want to have the file you want the version numbers of closed, too.

```
Function fCheckVersions(stFilename As String) As Boolean
'
' stFilename is the full URL to a document in a Document Library.
'
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim VersionWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim dlvVersions As Office.DocumentLibraryVersions
Dim dlvVersion As Office.DocumentLibraryVersion
Dim OldVersion As Excel.Workbook
Dim stExtension As String
Dim iPosExt As Long

viRow = 3
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Cells(viRow, 1) = stFilename

If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(stFilename) = True Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(stFilename, , True)
    Set dlvVersions = wb.DocumentLibraryVersions
    If dlvVersions.IsVersioningEnabled = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Cells(viRow, 3) = "Num"
        Versions = " & dlvVersions.Count"
        On Error GoTo VersionFailed:
        For Each dlvVersion In dlvVersions
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Cells(viRow, 4) = "Version: " & dlvVersion.Index
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Cells(viRow, 5) = "Modified Date: " & dlvVersion.Modified
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Cells(viRow, 6) = "Modified by: " & dlvVersion.ModifiedBy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Cells(viRow, 7) = "Comments: " & dlvVersion.Comments
                Set OldVersion = dlvVersion.Open()
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Cells(viRow, 8) = "FileName: " & OldVersion.Name
                If Workbooks.Count > 2 Then
                    Workbooks(3).Close SaveChanges:=False
                End If
            viRow = viRow + 1
        GoTo NextVersion:
VersionFailed:
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
        MsgBox "Fail"
NextVersion:
        Next dlvVersion
    End If
    wb.Close False
End If
Set wb = Nothing
DoEvents
End Function
```

Comment: It's absolutely bizarre that the `DocumentLibraryVersion` object doesn't have an attribute with the version number, but this does indeed seem to be the case. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863724.aspx