# compare workbooks version numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to compare version numbers of 2 workbooks without opening the 2nd one ( If it's possible) So far I've came up with two ideas but non of them works :(

```
If wb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("document version") = Workbooks("C:\Users\paw\Desktop\Test4\test2.xlsm").BuiltinDocumentProperties("document version") Then
```

and

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim strFilename As String
Dim abcd As String

strFilename = "C:\Users\paw\Desktop\Test4\test2.xlsm"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

abcd = fso.GetFileVersion(strFilename)
Debug.Print abcd

Set fso = Nothing
```

The second code is just to extract version number from file using certain path.

Something like this works just fine btw. but I really don't want the 2nd workbook to open:

```
If wb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("document version") = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\paw\Desktop\Test4\test22.xlsm").BuiltinDocumentProperties("document version") Then
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you try using ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat? Here are the enumerations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I'm not quite sure how to use it without opening the 2nd workbook.

Comment: FileFormat of the Workbook object returns an Enumeration value which corresponds to the version of Excel used to create the object. You can return this by first, getting the Workbook option, then returning the FileFormat property.

Comment: **object not option

Comment: @RyanWildry I think my second code is no good as I'm not trying to get the excel version of file , but the version number that you can find im file properties.

Comment: Looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326121/how-to-get-the-version-number-of-an-excel-workbook

Comment: I saw that before but there is still some workbook opening involved...

Comment: Then open the workbook, get the information needed, then close it.

Comment: Yup that's one way to do it (as I've mentioned in my original question), but is that even possible to do it without opening?

Comment: Not that I know of, properties of the workbook are sometimes only accessible by opening the file first. It may be possible reading the XML from the file with something like open XML. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx. I think opening it is probably easier.